# Preventing X numbers from select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script running to show a number in the select list options when the user check one specific value it will display a number refering to how much times he can pay his bill.

## Note this code:

```
var tabelaParcelas = [2,3,4,6,8,10,12];

$(document).ready(function(){
    update();
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    update();
})

function update(){
  var list = $('#instNum2'); // use selector only once whenever possible for better performance

  // clear any existing options from the dropdown list
  list.html("")

  // count checked boxes
  var checked_boxes = 0
  $(".check_list").each(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        checked_boxes++;
    }
  });

  // append options to the select list
  for(var i=0;i<checked_boxes;i++){
    var option = $("<option>", {value: tabelaParcelas[i], "text": tabelaParcelas[i]});
        list.append(option);
  }


}
```

That's correct! But the thing is, I need to display `1x` as well, and that's what's not showing at all, `1x` should be visible always no matter how much boxes you select, and other thing, when I select more than 7 boxes, the option keep producing empty options, while it should only keep displaying `12x` without appending any new...

Comment: show html too so that people can run your code and try to understand what you want.But don't think i am going to give answer. I am just saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tabelaParcelas = [2,3,4,6,8,10,12];

$(document).ready(function(){
    update();
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    update();
})

function update(){
  var list = $('#instNum2'); // use selector only once whenever possible for better performance

  // clear any existing options from the dropdown list
  list.html("")

  // count checked boxes
  var checked_boxes = 0
  $(".check_list").each(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        checked_boxes++;
    }
  });

  //add limit to check_boxes
  //This section was not in original code
  //  Could also do if(checked_boxes > tabelaParcelas.length) {checked_boxes = tabelaParcelas.length;}
  //Would make it more dynamic.
  //This is added to limit the number of options added to the length of the array at the top.  
  //This will prevent blank options from being added as requested in the question.
  if(checked_boxes > 6) {
      checked_boxes = 6;
  }

  //add 1x option to empty list
  //This was not in original code
  //This was added as the list was cleared when this function is run and they always wanted 1x to appear as an option.
  list.append("<option value='1' selected>1</option>");

  // append options to the select list
  for(var i=0;i<checked_boxes;i++){
    var option = $("<option>", {value: tabelaParcelas[i], "text": tabelaParcelas[i]});
        list.append(option);
  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the code for limit in check_boxes display the value undefined after selecting more than 6... Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like I had a typo.  In my add limit I had check_boxes rather than checked_boxes.  It is edited now.

Comment: Please explain your answer. Tell what was wrong with the original code, and how you've fixed it.

Comment: When the update function was called it would clear the list and they stated they always wanted 1x to show up so I made sure to add that after it was cleared out.  At the //add 1x option to empty list.  They also didn't want blank options being added if they are over the limit of the array so I checked it and set it back to the limit of the array so it would not add more and show blank ones.

Comment: @Chris, Please [edit] your answer to include the explanation.